# "boolean" nunique in pandas object dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### The goal

I have a long narrow dataframe `df` (30k x 15), and want to see for each row, if *all* the values are unique or not.

The values in the dataframe are not necessarily float or int values, but may also be objects. This questions is about the latter case, as it slows things down *a lot*. (I'm aware that objects will always be slower, but I'd still like to optimize that case.)

### The approach

What I have been doing:

```py
df.nunique(axis=1) == len(df.columns)
```

This takes 47sec. It is inefficient, because I do not actually care about the *number* of unique values, but the code still needs to calculate them.

### The improvement

I have improved this by creating a function `boolunique`:

```py
def boolunique(row):
    vals = set()
    for val in row:
        if val in vals:
            return False
        vals.add(val)
    return True
```

The results are a bit confusing:

- using it with `df.apply(boolunique, axis=1)` almost doubles the execution time, to 81sec; but
- using it with `pd.Series({n: boolunique(r) for n, r in df.iterrows()})` halves the time to 24sec.

The latter is better, but it *still* takes much longer than I would expect.

### The question

**Is there a more efficient way I'm overlooking?**

---

PS: I tried using a variant of the `boolunique` function as well (`lambda row: len(set(row)) == len(row)`), but the running times are virtually the same.

---

**edit**

Here is some sample code to create a similar dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pint
import pint_pandas
idx = pd.date_range('1940', '2020', freq='D')
vals = np.random.random_integers(0, 40, (len(idx), 15))
df = pd.DataFrame({n: pd.Series(column, idx).astype('pint[sec]') for n, column in enumerate(vals.T)})
```

The `.astype('pint[sec]')` turns the values into objects, and this is what slows the comparison down.

I'd like to write code that also efficiently handles objects.

(I'm aware that, in this particular case, I could speed things up by leaving out the conversion to `pint` objects. But I cannot control the datatype I'm handed; it may be a dataframe of floats, or of ints, ore of pint quantities, or a mix of all of the above.)

Comment: Can you provide any sample dataframe for the same?

Comment: Hey @LavSharma, I've added some sample code to the question.

Comment: Hey, @ElRudi! I've edited my answer, adding more information relevant to your situation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.is_unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_unique.html) :

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.is_unique, axis=1)
```

It should be faster than implementing the iteration and check for unique values yourself.